# How to build a netcore 3.0 Webapi and deploy to an Azure Linux app service

Tags: linux, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a netcore 3.0 Web api that I've developed and tested on Windows using Visual Studio 2019.

I have deployed it to a Windows Web app on a Windows app service plan. This runs as expected.

I then created a Linux app service plan with a net core 3.0 Linux Web app on azure using "executable" and not "Docker".

Next I attempted to publish my Web app from Visual Studio 2019 to this instance. It succeeds however my web app just gives the following fault

[image]

I have tried deploying as Linux-x64 and portable. I have also tried selecting framework dependent and self contained as the deployment mode.

Some simply show the error above, the other combinations just time out.

Is there an official MS guide to do what I am attempting to do above?

If not how can I diagnose the error. Can I remote in via SSH? Are there error logs anywhere?

Can I remotely debug the instance?

If not can I build and test the Linux version using the Linux subsystem for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure about how to deploy your application, you can create a new Devops project on Azure portal and import your source code later.

- Search for Devops Project
- Select .NET as application from the template click Next
- Select ASP.NET Core as application framework click Next
- Select Linux Web App as a Service
- Pass the necessary paramters in the next step and you are done

you should be able to compare and apply the same

Comment: I want to publish from Visual Studio. Why can't I do this? Is what I am trying to do wrong?

Comment: no i tried and it worked fine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-linux?view=vs-2019

Comment: Great but mine doesn't, that guide also doesn't detail what you should use for the configuration properties. Eg framework dependent etc, it appears to be for an older version of netcore and older visual studio.

Comment: Hmm I could help only this much, may be will try sometime later. Good luck

Comment: Appreciate the help either way. That link gives me a few other things to try.

Comment: Ok I tried the guide you linked below, same problem with the basic default code implying there might be some azure setup issues.